# Spring end-point always return 403 while checking role

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have integrated the `role` and want to manage the access of the specific service on the basis of the role.
An admin can create an **AGENT** and that agent came under the group of ADMIN user.

What I basically did have create a `1 to Many` relation ship because my user could have only 1 role.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Collection<User> users;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Collection<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Collection<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

And here I have the user which the group relation as well the group is also `1 TO MANY` because a user_admin can have multiple agents but agent could not have multiple admins.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled = false;
    private Role role;
    private UserGroup userGroup;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, Role role) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled, Role role, UserGroup userGroup) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.role = role;
        this.userGroup = userGroup;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @NotBlank
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = true)
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public UserGroup getUserGroup() {
        return userGroup;
    }

    public void setUserGroup(UserGroup userGroup) {
        this.userGroup = userGroup;
    }
}
```

At the time of creation of the user I specify the role and the group as well.

And in the `SecurityConfig` I have configure like this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(Constants.BASE_URL_FILE_UPLOADER + Constants.URL_UPLOAD_FILE).hasRole("ADMIN")                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new ContentSearcherAuthenticationEntryPoint());
}
```

But If I am accessing this end-point with the admin user I throws **forbidden** and also in the function when I access `authentication.getAuthorities()`it return **emptyList**

```
ResponseEntity<JsonNode> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Authentication authentication) {
    logger.info("Authentication is [{}] and user is [{}]", authentication.getAuthorities(), authentication.getName()); // []
}
```

I am confused in `UserDetailsService` I have also added the `GrantedAuthority` as well like this.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " Not Exists");
        }
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(),
                true, true, true, getAuthorities(user.getRole()));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(
            Role role) {

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Constants.ROLE_PREFIX + role.getName()));

        return authorities;
    }
}
```

What I am missing is there any more configuration I have to add ?

I am using JWT for the authentication purpose some thing should not to be added in this as well ?

Because when I get the `Authentication` in the JWT `successfulAuthentication` it shows the Authorities.

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.info("Auth in the successful is [{}]", authResult.getAuthorities()); // [ROLE_ADMIN]
}
```

Using Spring-Security core 5.0.9.

Comment: You have no mapping between User and Role, so Hibernate does not know how to fetch collection. Put OneToMany and ManyToOne annotations on your relations and fetching data should work.

Comment: I have it let me update it and add complete code.

Comment: How do you store Roles in the Database? When you say `hasRole("ADMIN");` Spring expects the Role in JWT to be `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it after getting the hint from @Reza Nasiri question basically I was not adding the `Authorities` when authenticating the `JWT` token now what I did is,

```
return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, getAuthorities("ADMIN");
```

In my `getAuthentication` function in `JWTAuthorizationFilter` class.

Comment: JWTAuthorizationFilter